# Custom Picker in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am following the link https://code.google.com/p/scroll-picker-view-for-android/ for development of the custom picker.
I am using the scroll picker view from the code. 
From the below code how to get the item which is selected ?

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scrollPickerView = new ScrollPickerView(this);
        scrollPickerView.addSlot(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.custom_list), 1, ScrollPickerView.ScrollType.Ranged);
        scrollPickerView.setSlotIndex(0, 13);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200);
        this.setContentView(scrollPickerView, params);
    }
```

I want to add a button below the picker. Once the user clicks on the button it should alert/toast the selected row text. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this wheel picker view**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
     // TODO: Externalize string-array
    String wheelMenu1[] = new String[]{"name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4", "name 5", "name 6","name 7","name 8","name 9"};
    String wheelMenu2[] = new String[]{"age 1", "age 2", "age 3"};
    String wheelMenu3[] = new String[]{"10", "20","30","40","50","60"};

    // Wheel scrolled flag
    private boolean wheelScrolled = false;

    private TextView text;
    private EditText text1;
    private EditText text2;
    private EditText text3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            initWheel1(R.id.p1);
            initWheel2(R.id.p2);
            initWheel3(R.id.p3);

            text1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r1);
            text2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r2);
            text3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r3);
            text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.result);
        }

    // Wheel scrolled listener
    OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener()
        {
            public void onScrollStarts(WheelView wheel)
                {
                    wheelScrolled = true;
                }

            public void onScrollEnds(WheelView wheel)
                {
                    wheelScrolled = false;
                    updateStatus();
                }
        };

    // Wheel changed listener
    private final OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener()
        {
            public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue)
                {
                    if (!wheelScrolled)
                        {
                            updateStatus();
                        }
                }
        };

    /**
     * Updates entered PIN status
     */
    private void updateStatus()
        {
            text1.setText(wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()]);
            text2.setText(wheelMenu2[getWheel(R.id.p2).getCurrentItem()]);
            text3.setText(wheelMenu3[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]);

            text.setText(wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()] + " - " + wheelMenu2[getWheel(R.id.p2).getCurrentItem()] + " - " + wheelMenu3[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]);
        }

    /**
     * Initializes wheel
     * 
     * @param id
     *          the wheel widget Id
     */

    private void initWheel1(int id)
        {
            WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
            wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
            wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
            wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
            wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
            wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
        }

    private void initWheel2(int id)
        {
            WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
            wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu2));
            wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
            wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
            wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
            wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
        }

    private void initWheel3(int id)
        {
            WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);

            wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu3));
            wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
            wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
            wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
            wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
        }

    /**
     * Returns wheel by Id
     * 
     * @param id
     *          the wheel Id
     * @return the wheel with passed Id
     */
    private WheelView getWheel(int id)
        {
            return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
        }

    /**
     * Tests wheel value
     * 
     * @param id
     *          the wheel Id
     * @param value
     *          the value to test
     * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
     */
    private int getWheelValue(int id)
        {
            return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
        }
}
```

Comment: The link you provided is to the list view not to the picker.
To the picker the link is https://code.google.com/p/scroll-picker-view-for-android/source/browse/trunk/samplecode/src/com/ttshrk/datetimepicker/sample/ListSampleActivity.java?r=13